# problemas mail php (envia doble email al correo)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, phpmailer

hola no se si alguien de aquí podría ayudarme, les cuento tengo el siguiente código, el cual funciona y todo envía el email, con todos los datos el problema es que me esta enviando doble el correo, osea hago el envió pero como a los segundos después vuelve a caer el mismo email(se duplica), no entiendo bien este es todo el código de la función como tal, el problema esta allí, ya que es como que si se repitiera o volviera a generar el bucle este código es único no lo tengo en mas archivos, aveces si funciona y envía un único email, pero muchas veces no, lo vuelve a duplicar alguien podría decirme mi error o algo que capten se lo agradeceré un montón el código se ve un poco largo pero no lo es en si.

```
 // obtiene un valor atraido por medio del enlace le llamo token o clave 
    $ACTIVACION_KEY= $_GET["verificar"];
      // conexion a la base de datos 
    include dirname(__DIR__, 2) . 'direccion de la base de datos';
    $conn = getDBConnection();
 // Poner a uno el campo emailconfirmado en la tabla precios esto dando a conocer que el usuario a confirmado su email por medio del valor de la llave o el codigo o valor atraido en el enlace de confirmación

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("update LCMN_PRECIO set EMAIL_CONFIRMADO=1 where ACTIVACION_KEY=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($ACTIVACION_KEY));
//hago una consulta por medio del valor traído del enlace para atraer los valores que contiene este mismo y los pongo en arreglos para usarlas después como variables 

    $sql= "select * from PRECIO where ACTIVACION_KEY='".$ACTIVACION_KEY."'";
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
    $NOMBRE= $row["NOMBRE"];
    $TELEFONO= $row["TELEFONO"];
    $CIUDAD= $row["CIUDAD"];
    $CP= $row["CODIGO_POSTAL"];
    $EMAIL= $row["EMAIL"];
    $DIRECCION= $row["DIRECCION"];
    $PREFERENCIA= $row["PREFERENCIA_CONECT"];
    $HORACONTACTO= $row["HORA_CONTACTO"];
    $POSTITLE= $row["POST_TITLE"];
    $TIPOE= $row["TIPO_E"];
    $FECHA= $row["TIMESTAMP"];
    $emailconf = $row['EMAIL_CONFIRMADO'];
       }

    $conn = null;
// este codigo hace el envio del correo con todo el mensaje y los valores que agrege, funciona y todo pero se esta duplicando

  $headers = "From: Correo electronico\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: correo electronico\r\n";
  $headers .= "Return-Path: correo electronico\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  $to = "correo electronico";
  $subject = " Confirmacion de solicitud";
  $message = "";
$message .= 'Hola, <br><br>';
    $message .= '<b>texto</b>:'.$POSTITLE. '<br>';
    $message .= '<ul>';
    $message .= '<li><b>Nombre</b>: '.$NOMBRE.'</li>';
    $message .= '<li><b>Email</b>: '.$EMAIL.'</li>';enter code here
    $message .= '<li><b>Telefono</b>: '.$TELEFONO.'</li>';
    $message .= '<li><b>Preferiencia de contacto</b>: '.$PREFERENCIA.'</li>';
    $message .= '<li><b>Horario en que prefiere ser contactado</b>: '.$HORACONTACTO.'</li>';
    $message .= '<li><b>Fecha de solicitud</b>: '.$FECHA.'</li>';
    $message .= '<li><b>Tipo</b>: '.$TIPOE.'</li>';
    $message .= '</ul>';
    $message .= 'Otros datos:<br>';
    $message .= '<ul>';
    $message .= '<li><b>Lugar de procedencia </b>: '.$CIUDAD.'</li>';
     $message .= '<li><b>Codigo postal</b>: '.$CP.'</li>';
    $message .= '</ul>';
// envio del mail funciona pero duplica

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
//aqui va el diseño de la pagina html, la estructura pero no afecta o eso creo, no contiene mas variables en el html esta basado en wordpress
```

codigo corto html

Answer (score 0):

¿Has comprobado que ne estás ejecutando dos veces el mismo código? Usando, por ejemplo, dos veces `require()`.

Puedes poner `exit();` al final del código o `echo "Enviando correo";` para saber si es así.

Ademas tienes la etiqueta [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) pero no parece que estes usando phpmailer.
Te aconsejo que uses phpmailer ya que evitarás un monton de problemas relacionados con malas configuraciones o mensajes en la carpeta Spam.
Y `$headers` deberia contener algo mejor que `From: Correo electronico`.

Comment: que tal he revisado el codigo como tal pero no hallo que lo este usando mas de dos veces, es el unico con las unicas variables no uso ese codigo para mas funciones, el codigo es raro por que aveces funciona aveces no jaja, pero de que envia el correo si lo envia, solo que aveces llega una vez o dos veces, la mayoria llega el correo dos veces lo duplica, cuando solo debe de llegar una vez, tendra que provar lo del exit();